# What plant/flower is this?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, flowers

This plant has been growing in my friend's garden. What plant/flower is it?

[image: unknown]
[image: unknown]
[image: unknown plant]

Comment: https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/872/7456 - where does this unusual beauty grow?

Answer (score 5):

That’s an *[Arisaema tortuosum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arisaema_tortuosum)*, a whipcord cobra lily, fittingly named for the very elongated spadix.

While in many cobra lilies the spathe, the tube-petal-like part around the spadix, takes the show, here the unusually long spadix -which carries the actual flowers - is eye-catching.